# Changing database servers

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql

So I am still pretty new to databases and I am trying to wrap my head around how a database server such as PostgreSQL, MySQL etc stores a database. Say I create some database using a client application such as `psql` and later decide to access the same database using `mysql`, would that be possible? Or the databases created by a specific database server are exclusive to that server only? And where and how exactly are these databases physically stored in the file system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Say I create some database using a client application such as psql and later decide to access the same database using mysql, would that be possible?

No. As @tadman infers, the different databases have very different access tools and methods.

> Or the databases created by a specific database server are exclusive to that server only?

The big name databases can work almost anywhere: DB2, Postgres, Oracle and MySQL, can work on 99% of servers. An exception is MS SQLserver, which only works on Microsoft servers.

> And where and how exactly are these databases physically stored in the file system?

Ahh.. so many answers to that, it's best to come back with a separate Q noting the specific database you want and the server operating system.

---

Side note: reading between the lines of your Q, you may want to explore SQLite. With SQLite, the database is *one file* on your platform.

Answer (score 1):

A client like `psql` is *extremely* database specific, it speaks the Postgres protocol and that's not interchangeable with MySQL.

Databases, likewise, are stored in a format that's not easily swapped. There's often incompatibility between versions. The backup, or `.sql` dump file *can* be copied from one server to another and restored, though.

Pick a platform that suits your need and stick with it until you know it really well.